# How to recovery files from lost a deleted partition

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, partitioning

I've deleted the wrong partition of my disk where is my ubuntu, and I have important files there, is there any way to recovery them?

Comment: I understood that is a duplicated question, but as you can see with a different answer from what you have posted, there is any possibility to keep this thread undeleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### COMPLETE REVISION:

I suggested using [RIP Linux](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/) because I forgot the name of the actual tool included in it that I used. I checked, and it turns out that the tool is called PhotoRec. As I said, it scans a partition looking for patterns that resemble certain file types, then copies these to a different location.

It turns out that PhotoRec is actually available from Ubuntu's APT repository, so if you currently have Ubuntu installed and running, or you currently have it running live, then you can install PhotoRec and run it in Ubuntu. This might be more convenient.

Also, I found that PhotoRec has a relative that might be more useful in this situation: TestDisk. TestDisk can perform other operations including but not limited to restoring partition tables. If you haven't made any major changes to the disk since deleting the partition, this might allow you to restore the partition and most of the files on it so that you can access most of your old files by going to My Computer. Note that you probably won't be able to boot the partition after restoring it, and you will probably lose all of your new partitions.

Both tools can be found here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Main_Page